# TikZ error for externalized graphics but output is correct

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, debugging

This is not an MWE per se, but it is the code I boiled the problem down to. Note: it does not produce an error.

The issue is that once I somehow managed to get an error for any TikZ or pgfplots graphic (due to any sort of mishap: missing bracket, semicolon or any other thing I suppose), the error message "`--shell-escape -halt-
on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname`" (and so forth...) comes up. Yet all graphics and edits to them get produced properly as far as I can tell. But the message won't go away.

**I'm at a point where I'm totally clueless about it all. Is there a catch in connection to externalized TikZ/pgfplots-graphics?** Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated. :)

### Notes

The error message only goes away if I remove/comment out

- the `footnotetext`- and `\addtocounter`-commands after each `figure` with a `tikzpicture` in it or
- `\tikzexternalize`

Does the editor (TeXstudio) make a difference?

- No, the problem appears in the same manner, whether I hit `F1` in TeXstudio or run pdflatex from the command line.

### Log for running pdflatex from Windows' cmd

http://pastebin.com/vHqE5isd

### Log for running pdflatex --shell-escape from Windows' cmd

http://pastebin.com/0JZCij4T

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
    newtxtext,
    amsmath,
    subcaption,
    biblatex
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    external,
}
\tikzexternalize

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tp]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
        \centering
        a\\
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \subcaption[Something short.]{Something longer. So there is some text.\footnotemark\footnotemark}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
        \centering
        b\\
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \subcaption[Text.]{Some longer text and a few words}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-2}
\footnotetext{\cite[Cp.][12]{Smith}}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{\cite[Cp.][23]{Jones}}



\end{document}
```

### Preamble relating to TikZ and pgfplots with style definitions

```
%% TikZ

\usetikzlibrary{
    external,
    plotmarks,
    math,
    calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,
    decorations.pathreplacing,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    decorations.shapes,
    decorations.text,
    shapes,
    shapes.geometric,
    shapes.symbols,
    matrix,
    patterns,
    intersections,
    fit
}
\tikzexternalize

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

%% pgfplots

\usepgfplotslibrary{
    groupplots,
    external
    }

\pgfplotsset{
every axis/.append style={
%%
%tick label style = {font=\sffamily\small\sansmath},
%every axis label = {font=\sffamily\small\sansmath},
%legend style = {font=\sffamily\small\sansmath},
%label style = {font=\sffamily\small\sansmath},
%
xmajorgrids={true},
ymajorgrids={true},
xminorgrids={true},
yminorgrids={true},
%
%line width=1pt,
%thick,
%
minor tick num=1,
%axis lines=middle,
%tick align=center,
compat=1.10,
},
every tick/.append style={
black,
thick
},
/pgf/number format/.cd,
use comma,
1000 sep={\,},
}

\tikzexternalize
```

### File list

```
*File List*
scrartcl.cls    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script document class (article)
scrkbase.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (type area)
newtxtext.sty    2014/04/07 v1.25
fontaxes.sty    2014/03/23 v1.0d Font selection axes
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
subcaption.sty    2013/02/03 v1.1-62 Sub-captions (AR)
 caption.sty    2013/05/02 v3.3-89 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2013/05/02 v1.6-88 caption3 kernel (AR)
biblatex.sty    2013/11/25 v2.8a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty    2013/11/25 v2.8a programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB
)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    
standard.bbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.bbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.cbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ts1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 english.lbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
  ts1cmr.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
 t1ntxrx.fd    2012/12/25 v1.0
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Comment: It worked fine for me with MikTeX 2.9 and TeXnic Center with LaTeX->PDF.  There were supposedly 3 Bibtex errors.  Why is Bibtex running?

Comment: Huh, what exactly do you mean by "supposedly"? :) Bibtex shouldn't be called.

Comment: That's what the log said.  There were 3 Bibtex erros.  No details were given.  BTW, would you like a copy of the picture?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks, this isn't necessary since I get it to work from time to time.

Comment: Work fine for me : textlive 2013 and last PgfTikz 3.0.0

Comment: @Tarass I believe you. Like I wrote, once I get a TikZ/pgfplots error due to any sort of mishap (missing bracket, semicolon or any other thing), all hell seems to break loose.

Comment: What error message? What you posted isn't an error message or doesn't appear so. It looks like options you'd pass to the compiler (`pdflatex` or whatever).

Comment: TeX Studio appears to expect you to use `bibtex`. On the other hand, your source requires `biber`. Does TeX Studio run additional scripts automatically? If so, does it know to run `biber`? In any case, switch to the command line for trouble shooting. Editors obfuscate stuff from you. (You don't want to run in non-stop mode if you want to find the source of the error.)

Comment: @cfr Hm, about the biber settings: [this is the first option I set](http://imgur.com/C4jSDhF), [and this the second](http://imgur.com/byuCfi0). Did you mean this or some other setting? (more comments coming...)

Comment: @cfr The .log file for the command line run via `pdflatex`: http://pastebin.com/vHqE5isd and this is the .log file for `pdflatex --shell-escape`: http://pastebin.com/0JZCij4T Does that provide more helpful info? To me they are basically the same. I quit both on the first interaction/error as apparently the very first figure throws an error but this time did not get produced at all.

Comment: @cfr It runs through without warning/errors if I comment out `\tikzexternalize`.

Comment: About `biber`: I had nothing specific in mind. Just the screen shot only showed `bibtex` and I know that some editors basically have to be tricked by telling them that the way to run `bibtex`, say, is to run `biber...` so since somebody mentioned `bibtex` errors, it seemed worth checking.

Comment: Your .log file for the case `pdflatex --shell-escape` requests you to look into `K04/Bilder/K04_0.log`. This log file contains the error which aborted the externalization. Could you also provide this log file? Or summarize its error messages?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I don't know why I spotted your comment earlier but I am really glad I revisited this question. Here you go: [K04_4.log](http://pastebin.com/hjxu2QMG) ... and actually, the main log file suggests to look into the files going up to K04_9.log. Should I provide them as well?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Interesting, they all containt the same error in regards to this: `Dies\footnotetext{\cite[Vgl.][421]{PuenteLeon_2012_Messtechnik}.} wird nun`. I don't understand that at all. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You found an incompatibility: the `external` library and `biblatex`'s `\cite[][]` syntax are incompatible.

---

The bug has been fixed; will become part of the next stable PGF.

---

According to the additional information provided in  K04_4.log , TeX expected a `$` sign when processing `\cite[Vgl.][421]{PuenteLeon_2012_Messtechnik}`. I guessed that this could be related to the underscore: it is a reserved token in math mode and requires `$` if it is present within the normal text. Clearly, yours is not a normal text - but what if it becomes one during externalization?

Anyway, you can turn your example into a "real" minimal (non)working example if you write `\cite[Cp.][23]{Jones_a}` instead of `\cite[Cp.][23]{Jones}` (I introduced an underscore).

The bug is that the external library redefines `\cite` in order to catch all undefined symbols and communicate them as warnings into the log file of your original .tex file. This feature which collects warnings expects at most one set of square brackets after `\cite` and fails to process yours. This needs to be fixed; I will take care of it (no need to submit an extra bug report).

A workaround for now is to disable this feature which communicates unresolved `\cite` commands. Risk of this work-around: you may not realize that externalized images contain `\cite` which could not be resolved. In your minimal example, no tikzpicture environment even contains `\cite`, so it is entirely harmless.

Here is the example with the workaround:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
    amsmath,
    subcaption,
    biblatex
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    external,
}
\tikzexternalize[
    failed ref warnings for={%
        \ref,%
        %\cite,% DISABLE THIS
        \pageref},
]

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tp]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
        \centering
        a\\
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \subcaption[Something short.]{Something longer. So there is some text.\footnotemark\footnotemark}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
        \centering
        b\\
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \subcaption[Text.]{Some longer text and a few words}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-2}
\footnotetext{\cite[Cp.][12]{Smith}}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{\cite[Cp.][23]{Jones_a}}



\end{document}
```

Comment: After weeks of confusion, this is such a relief to read.

Comment: ... man. Silly me, I must have totally overlooked your comment roughly two weeks ago. :/ To make it all maybe a bit clearer if anyone else is curious: Christian is right in his "assumption", I neither have `\ref`, `\cite` nor `\pageref` in a tikzpicture environment. I might very well at some point in the following weeks but then it is  going to be different.

Comment: Would you happen to have any ETA of your fix? If so, a short note about it would be great. Also, maybe you could include this information in the post above? :)

Comment: PGF has very very long release cycles, so: no ETA. I will see if I can ship a copy of the external lib with the next `pgfplots` release (in which case you would need to use `\usepgfplotslibrary{external}`).

Comment: Good to know, thank you for your quick reply. (I use the external library already btw.)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but I dont have enough reps for a comment. I am using TeXlipse and MikTeX and the following error occured after copying and pasting your code from above:

```
Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "document-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{document}\input{document}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'document-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'document-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture. \end{tikzpicture} (followed by: )
```

It says `document-figure0` could't be created, so I did it myself by hand and created an `document-figure0.pdf` (other extensions are also given in the error message) after that both errors for both `tikzpicture` regions have gone away because no pdf file can be created

```
document-figure0.pdf: xpdf: reading PDF image failed
pdflatex.exe>  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Hope this helps to come a step forward.

## Update 1

I will eloborate my answer with a few images! But in short adding `--shell-escape` as a command line switch for `pdflatex.exe` did the job.

## Error

[image]

## Edit command line

[image]

## Solved

I actually changed the height of the second rectangle (to 2) so to force two different MD5 sums but this will of course work with you initial example, too
[image]

There are other threads here on tex.se which I'd like to link against. So please see [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14030/attempt-to-export-eps-figures-from-tikz-fails), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22374/externalize-graphics-when-using-pgfplots-doesnt-work-miktex-2-9), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169371/error-using-lualatex-and-tikzexternalize-to-compile-document-with-pgfplots) and [4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153783/tikz-externalize-causing-problems-with-template).

## Update 2

I missed to say what *henry* termed *Preamble relating to TikZ and pgfplots with style definitions* is in the external.tex file and his *MWE* part is in the document.tex file. Which I am using in the preamble (please correct me if something different was intended).

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\input{external.tex}
```

I had to realize *henry* even knows all this: [5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170291/tikz-wont-let-me-externalize-and-halts-on-error)

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It's worth asking (to rule it out): are you successful in running any code to produce and include an externalized TikZ figure? If not, unfortunately there is no merit in testing this on your end.

Comment: @henry Yes I could produce the final pdf WITH externalization. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: The binary folder of MikTeX is part of my path variable since I do a lot of thing manually via console and TeXlipse will require it I believe. So make this sure when using the above setup.